# How to count the amount of files returned by the REMOVE-ITEM command

Tags: powershell

I have this comand

```
Get-ChildItem -path Z:\htdocs\zz | where { $_.Length -eq 2254 } | ?{Remove-Item $_.fullname}
```

I would like it to also return the amount of files deleted/removed so I can compare it with a variable (like N).

Comment: You probably mean `| %` rather than `| ?`; the `?` is an alias for `Where-Object`, whereas you seem to be expecting `ForEach-Object`, which is aliased by `%`.

Comment: FWIW, that's why I don't generally use aliases - if I use the full name of the cmdlet, I _know_ what I'm getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
Get-ChildItem -path "c:\temp" -file | where Length -eq 2254 | %{
    try
    {
        Remove-Item $_.FullName
        $CountDeleted++
    }
    catch
    {
        $CountNotDeleted++
    }

}

"Result : {0} file(s) deleted, {1} file(s) cant removed" -f $CountDeleted, $CountNotDeleted
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example when you don't need a oneliner:

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem -Path "Z:\htdocs\zz" | Where-Object { $_.Length -eq 2254 }
Remove-Item -Path $Files.Fullname  
Write-Host "Deleted $($Files.Count) files"
```

Comment: Hi, your code returned an error -> PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $Files = Get-ChildItem -Path "Z:\htdocs\zz" | Where-Object { $_.Length -eq 2254 } Remove-Item -P
ath $Files.Fullname
Where-Object : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Remove-Item'.
At line:1 char:47
+ ... tdocs\zz" | Where-Object { $_.Length -eq 2254 } Remove-Item -Path $Fi ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Where-Object], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WhereObjectCommand

Comment: How do you start the script? Use powershell_ise and copy the code into the gui and press f5

Comment: @EBGreen which other standrad windows tool should I use to edit my scripts? Notepad or what?

Comment: Visual Studio Code. The ISE environment is not an accurate representation of a script running pretty much anywhere else.